# Change the color of a automatic generated NavBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode4.5

So I've created a tab bar application with more than five tabs and therefore a automatic generated Navigation bar comes to life. Fair enough, only thing is, that I want a Black opaque Navigation bar. Seen the questions about this asked before, but none of the info there helped me any. Anyone has a complete code for this? What to put in the .h and .m file?

I want the navigation bar black, the "edit"-button black, the "done" button black, the "back"-button black and also the other automatic generated navigation bars to be black. I'm sorry if I'm asking to much here, but there ain't so much info on the particular topic.

In advance, thanks!

Best regards,
Øyvind Larsen Runestad.

Comment: what do you mean by automatic generated nav bar, tab bar does not generate auto nav bar.

Comment: When add more than five tab bar itens, it generates a "more"-page with a navigation bar on top like in the iPod-app.

Comment: have you tried the `-setTintColor:` method of the `UINavigationBar` yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404197/how-to-set-the-navigation-bar-color-of-the-tab-bar-configure-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the property you're looking for:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor;
```

As for changing the color of the items, it's a matter of changing the color of every single `UINavigationItem`. See this question to know how to do it:

[Change UINavigationItem colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314703/change-uinavigationitem-colour)

As for "What to put in the .h and .m file?" you should write the code whenever you need to change the color of the items, so say that you need it when the view is loaded, then you do it in the viewDidLoad method, provided that you have already added the navigation bar.